# Regex get value between parentheses

Tags: regex, go

I have a line like: `10 lessons (40h 25m)` and I need to get the duration value and duration unit between parentheses using two regexps. 1st regex to get dur. value and second for unit.

**Example:**

1. `10 lessons (40h 25m)` - get **40** and **h**
2. `2 lessons (50m)` - get **50** and **m**
3. `25 lessons (3d 10h 23m)` - get **3** and **d**

**Note:**

I can't use one regex for this purpose. My JSON structure:

```
{
  "duration": {
    "unit": {
      "regex": "<regex>"
      //props..
    },
    "value": {
      "regex": "<regex>"
      //props..
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I used [**regexp2**](https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2) engine for getting the functionality of lookarounds.

Comment: Can you refer to capturing groups? I'm asking mainly because not being able to do so would explain why you'd want to use 2 regexs rather than one. It could also help if you disclosed which regex flavour you're using (e.g. perl's `\K` would be useful if you can't use capturing groups)

Comment: Looks like go doesn't support `\K` nor lookarounds, without those nor capturing groups I'm not sure your task is feasible

Comment: I mean, I don't think this can be solved using go's regexs. I'm not familiar at all with go or obviously your application, but I'd start looking into alternatives (pre-processing or post-processing)

Comment: @Aaron, I started using [regexp2](https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2), so I can use lookarounds. Now it may be easier to find a solution.

Comment: @Mandy8055, yeah, [first](https://regex101.com/r/qqx5mS/1), [second](https://regex101.com/r/qqx5mS/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try the below regex's to get your requirements:

```
(?<=\()\d+ --> to get the duration
(?<=\(\d+)[a-zA-Z] --> to get the units
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(?<=\()\d+`** - Represents positive look behind matching one or more digit just before a `(`.
>
> **`[a-zA-Z]`** - Represents a single character which is just followed by `(` along with one or more digits.

[image: pict]

You can find the demo of the above regexes in [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/qqx5mS/11) and [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/qqx5mS/10)

Comment: `Go` doesn't support lookarounds.

Comment: Completely aggreed @revo. But please read the comment associated with the question. OP used a library called [regexp2](https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2). There it supports lookarounds. After that only I put this answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure the lookaheads you have at the start of your two regexs are useful. In particular what it changes it that your regexes will only match the last occurences of brackets, but I don't think OP specified whether there could be multiple pairs of bracket and which to chose in this case

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. Updated the same. I thought otherwise that's why I put that. Pleas have a look now. Please do let me know if I'm missing something else.

Comment: Fair enough. But it seems those positive lookaheads are redundant.

Comment: I guess you're referring the last ones. Isn't it? First one I updated already.

Comment: No both. You don't need `(?=\w |\w\))` and `(?= |\))`.

Comment: Thanks again @revo updated the answer. I've much to learn. :(